# How to delete object constructed via placement new operator?

Tags: c++, templates, new-operator, destructor, placement-new

```
char * buf = new char[sizeof(T)];
new (buf) T;
T * t = (T *)buf;
//code...
//here I should destruct *t but as it is argument of template and can be
//instantiated via basic types as well (say int) so such code 
/*t->~T();*/
//is incorrect (maybe correct? Strange, but it works on VS 2005 for basic types.)
//and this code 
/*delete t;*/ 
//crashes the program.
delete [] buf;
```

So what is correct way to destruct `t`?

P.S. The code above is only for describing my problem, and have not real relationship with code I'm going to write. So please don't give answers like (Why use placement `new` instead of non-placement? or something similar)

Comment: Instead of `T *t = (T*)buf;` you should be doing: `T *t = new (buf) T:`. This allows you to avoid that suspicious looking casts (all casts are suspicious, but this one in particular because in most circumstances casting from `char*` to `T*` will be an aliasing violation.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> ...*instantiated via basic types as well (say `int`) so such code 
>   
> `t->~T();` is incorrect*...

Wrong. That code is legal and correct in template code even if `T` can be a primitive type.

C++ standard: 5.4.2

> 5.2.4 ***Pseudo destructor call [expr.pseudo]***
>
> 1. The use of a
>      pseudo-destructor-name after a dot `.` or arrow `->` operator represents
>      the destructor for the non-class type named by type-name. The result
>      shall only be used as the operand for the function call `operator ()`,
>      and the result of such a call has type void. The only effect is the
>      evaluation of the postfix expression before the dot or arrow.
> 2. The left hand side of the dot operator shall be of scalar type. The left
>      hand side of the arrow operator shall be of pointer to scalar type.
>      This scalar type is the object type. The type designated by the
>      pseudo destructor- name shall be the same as the object type.
>      Furthermore, the two type-names in a pseudodestructor- name of the
>      form `::opt nested-name-specifieropt type-name :: ˜ type-name` shall
>      designate the same scalar type. The cv-unqualified versions of the
>      object type and of the type designated by the pseudo-destructor-name
>      shall be the same type.

Comment: late question but what happens if you simply free the memory without destructing the object?

Comment: @ColinHicks The object will not go through its destructor (obviously).  If the object is implemented in such a way that the destructor performs necessary cleanup, e.g. closing files, destroying contained sub-objects, releasing mutexes or other shared resources, then this cleanup will not happen, possibly leading to memory or other resource leaks, files being corrupt due to lack of correct closure, etc.

Answer (score 12):

You first destruct the object by directly calling the destructor:

```
t->~T();
```

Then you destroy the memory by calling `delete[]` on the pointer returned from `new[]`:

```
delete []buf;
```

Answer (score 7):

Call the destructor

```
T * t = (T *)buf;
t->~T();
```

then free memory with `delete[] buf`. Calling destructors explicitly is exactly how it is done for objects created with placement `new`.

Answer (score 3):

The memory was actually allocated using `char*`; **which you are properly freeing using** `delete[] buf`. You just need to call the destructor `t->~T()` in this case for `t`. No need to `delete t;`.

**Placement** `new` in this case, is used only to construct the object not for the memory allocation.

Comment: Hey guys is this answer true? Will the buffer be deallocated when calling destructor of `t`. If yes, then how can I avoid it (i.e destruct only `*t`, but keep buffer memory to allocate there some object again)?

Comment: @Mihran, may be you have misunderstood my answer: I am already saying, `The memory was actually allocated using char*; which you are properly freeing using delete[]`. Calling destructor for `t->~T()` is needed, no need to `delete t;` You must be doing `delete[] buf;` which you are already doing correctly.