# How can I destroy an unknown type allocated with a placement new in C++?

Tags: c++, destructor, new-operator, delete-operator, placement-new

For example:

```
template <typename T> void foo(T *data, size_t count)
{
    T *t = reinterpret_cast<T*>(::operator new(sizeof(T) * count));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        new (&t[i]) T(data[i]);
    }

    // ...

    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        // How do I destroy t[i]?
    }
    ::operator delete(reinterpret_case<void*>(t));
}
```

I assume that I cannot simply call `t[i].~T()` because `T` might not be a class.

Comment: `t[i].~T()` ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730403/how-to-delete-object-constructed-via-placement-new-operator?rq=1