# Confusion about deleting objects created via placement new

Tags: c++, memory-management, placement-new

I am not absolutely sure what is happening in the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    double dummy{42};
    static void* operator new(std::size_t size, void* p)
    {
        std::cout << R"(Calling placement "operator new" for size )"
                  << size << '\n';
        return ::operator new(size, p);
    }

    Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Foo::Foo()" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "~Foo::Foo()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    void* buf_heap = new char[128] {};
    Foo* pFoo_heap = new(buf_heap) Foo; // placement allocation

    // why does this line call the correct operator delete?
    delete pFoo_heap;

    // the line above seems to be equivalent to:
    // pFoo_heap->~Foo();
    // ::operator delete(buf_heap);
}
```

I know that whenever one uses placement `new` when constructing an object, the destructor should be manually called, followed by a call to release the memory (usually via `::operator delete` or `::operator delete[]`, or `free`, depending on how placement `new` is implemented), see e.g. [How to delete object constructed via placement new operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6730403/3093378)

However, in my code above, I created a `Foo` object which I placed in heap-allocated memory. Then, when I call `delete pFoo_heap`, the destructor is automatically invoked (this I understand), however it seems also that the memory is also released (`buf_heap` in this case). That is, if I try after to do `::operator delete[](buf_heap);` I'm getting a segfault.

So basically the line

```
delete pFoo_heap;
```

seems to be equivalent to

```
pFoo_heap->~Foo(); 
::operator delete[](buf_heap);
```

Is this indeed the case (or it is just UB)? Why is the memory allocated in `buf_heap` de-allocated? Or, in other words, does `delete pFoo_heap;` know where the memory came from, even if allocated via a placement `new`?

Comment: Guess: you are lucky because your placed object and the heap block start at the same address.  Try allocating `pFoo_heap` in the middle of  `buf_heap` and see what happens.

Comment: @RichardCritten great comment, I didn't think about this. So it is a nice example of UB...

Answer (score 3):

You asked:

```
// why does this line call the correct operator delete?
delete pFoo_heap;

// the line above seems to be equivalent to:
// pFoo_heap->~Foo();
// ::operator delete(buf_heap);
```

That is not true. Your code is subject to undefined behavior. From the C++ Standard:

> **5.3.5 Delete**
>
> 2 If the operand has a class type, the operand is converted to a pointer type by calling the above-mentioned conversion function, and the converted operand is used in place of the original operand for the remainder of this section. In the first alternative (*delete object*), the value of the operand of `delete` may be a null pointer value, a pointer to a non-array object created by a previous *new-expression*, or a pointer to a subobject (1.8) representing a base class of such an object (Clause 10). If not, the behavior is undefined.

In your case, `pFoo_heap` was not created by a *new-expression*, `buf_heap` was created by a *new-expression*. You need to use:

```
pFoo_heap->~Foo();
delete [] buf_heap;
```

for a well behaved program.

Comment: That is indeed the proper way to do things.

Comment: Thanks for the standard reference. I knew that indeed I should call first the dtor, then eventually release the memory, but wasn't sure why my snippet seem to work. But the line *"a pointer to a non-array object created by a previous new-expression"* seem to take in consideration also placement new, isn't it? As it is still a *new-expression*.

Comment: In 5.3.4, placement `new` seems to be a *new-expression*, so imo `pFoo_heap` was created by a *new-expression*. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @vsoftco, The placement `new` in  section 5.3.4 addresses all forms of placement `new` other than the one we are discussing here. The placement `new` that we are discussing here is more clearly mentioned in section 18.6.1.3. That section says *Intentionally performs no other action.* Also, there's a small section at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new that talks about the placement `new` we are discussing.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the memory allocated in `buf_heap` de-allocated?

Because you're de-allocating it. Note that `buf_heap == pFoo_heap`, so when you do `delete pFoo_heap` that happens to work exactly as if you had done `new Foo` to begin with - the pointer you're deleting is pointing to memory that was previously allocated with `new`. So it... "works"...

Comment: Yes, but indeed is super bad, because if I do `new(buf_heap + 42) Foo`, then all bets are off.